# how to search on a same field in 1 table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

how to search on a same field in 1 table

SELECT `id`, `issues`, `status`
FROM  `docus`
WHERE `status` LIKE '%Done%'
AND  `issue` LIKE  '%Other%'
AND  `issue` LIKE  '%Transfer%'
ORDER BY id

i tried to this but got zero result

Comment: The query above is looking for records where all of these values available in single record. Try replacing AND with OR.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean

```
(issue like '%Other%' OR issue like '%transfer%')
```

unless you want to fetch rows that have both Transfer and Other in their issue column

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to match any of the following. if that's the case use `OR` instead of `AND` operator:

```
SELECT id, issues, `status`
FROM docus 
WHERE `status` LIKE '%Done%' OR
      issues LIKE '%Other%' OR
      issues LIKE '%Transfer%' 
ORDER BY id
```

OR

```
SELECT id, issues, `status`
FROM docus 
WHERE `status` LIKE '%Done%' AND
      (issues LIKE '%Other%' OR
      issues LIKE '%Transfer%' )
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your SQL query reformatted, which should get you the information you want.

```
SELECT id, issues, status 
FROM docus 
WHERE status LIKE '%Done%' 
AND (issue LIKE '%Other%' OR issue LIKE '%Transfer%') 
ORDER BY id
```